# "No such file error" when importing PN532Interface.h

Tags: arduino, nfc, spi, arduino-ide, pn532

I am trying to get the NFC shield working using SPI communication. 
I did follow all the instructions exactly as explained in
[Seeed Wiki - NFC Shield Setup](http://wiki.seeedstudio.com/NFC_Shield_V2.0/#software-libraries-installation).

Here is the code I tried:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <PN532/PN532_SPI/PN532_SPI.h>

PN532_SPI pn532spi(SPI, 10);
NfcAdapter nfc = NfcAdapter(pn532spi);

void setup(void) {
    Serial.begin(115200); // begin serial communication
    Serial.println("NDEF Reader");
    nfc.begin(); // begin NFC communication
}

void loop(void) {

    Serial.println("\nScan an NFC tag\n");
    if (nfc.tagPresent()) // Do an NFC scan to see if an NFC tag is present
    {
        NfcTag tag = nfc.read(); // read the NFC tag into an object, nfc.read() returns an NfcTag object.

        tag.print(); // prints the NFC tags type, UID, and NDEF message (if available)
    }
    delay(500); // wait half a second (500ms) before scanning again (you may increment or decrement the wait time)
}
```

Here is the error I am getting.

```
ResolveLibrary(PN532/PN532/PN532Interface.h)
In file included from D:\Dropbox\Ardruino\Seed NFC Reader\Seeed\ReadTagWithSPI

\ReadTagWithSPI.ino:9:0:
  -> candidates: []

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\Seeed_Arduino_NFC-master

\src/PN532/PN532_I2C/PN532_I2C.h:9:10: fatal error: PN532/PN532/PN532Interface.h: No such file 

or directory

 #include "PN532/PN532/PN532Interface.h"

          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

compilation terminated.

Using library SPI at version 1.0 in folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr

\libraries\SPI 
Using library PN532_SPI in folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\PN532_SPI (legacy)
Using library Seeed_Arduino_NFC-master at version 1.1.0 in folder: C:\Program Files 

(x86)\Arduino\libraries\Seeed_Arduino_NFC-master 
Using library Wire at version 1.0 in folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino

\avr\libraries\Wire 
exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino Uno.
```

Comment: the error message is pretty clear. you're missing a file so I guess you forgot to do step 3?

Comment: Do you have the file that it clearly says is missing?  Where is it on your computer?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ArduinoIDE use `Sketch -> Manage Libraries ->Library Manager`

- Enter PN532 in the search field and install the lib `Adafruit PN532` from there.

This ensures its placed in the right directory. Probably your libs are in a different thanin the Afafruit example.